# How to remove null cases from a List(List(List())) in scala?

Tags: scala, collections

I want only valid values from a List(List(List())), for example,

```
List(List(List(())), List(List(())), List(List(())), List(List(())), List(List(())), List(List(book eraser -> pen , confidence :66.0)))
List(List(List(())), List(List(Ink -> pen eraser , confidence :100.0)), List(List(())), List(List(pen Ink -> eraser , confidence :100.0)), List(List(())), List(List(Ink eraser -> pen , confidence :100.0)))
```

I need only the inside strings,

```
book eraser -> pen , confidence :66.0
Ink -> pen eraser , confidence :100.0
pen Ink -> eraser , confidence :100.0
Ink eraser -> pen , confidence :100.0
```

Comment: that's with the `:` syntax? Unless it's a custom operator of yours, it doesn't look like valid scala code.

Comment: The first I shown was I got now...It got after some calculations. So only true cases value will be produced. "confidence : 66.0" was got from that calculation. The whole line "book eraser -> pen , confidence :66.0" is a string. But I need only this valid strings...not LIst(List(...

Comment: Oh ok, got it now. You should make the types explicit then. That being said, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write a recursive method like so, you can pull out the strings regardless of the nesting.  (`flatten` only works if everything is nested to the same depth.)

```
def allStrings[A](xs: List[A]): List[String] = {
  val ss = List.newBuilder[String]
  def decompose(xs: List[_]) { xs match {
    case (s: String) :: more => ss += s; decompose(more)
    case (l: List[_]) :: more => decompose(l); decompose(more)
    case x :: more => decompose(more)
    case Nil =>
  }}
  decompose(xs)
  ss.result
}
```

That said, this is a weird way to store data.

(Note: all the `decompose(more)` calls are tail-recursive, so you won't have stack overflow problems.  `decompose(l)` is normal recursion, so if your lists are nested more than a thousand or so layers deep, you probably want to do it a different way (e.g. heap-based breadth-first search).)

Answer (score 2):

The example you provided isn't exactly clear, but I looks like a couple of `flatten` might help:

```
val a = List(List(List()), List(List("book eraser -> pen , confidence :66.0")), List(List())) 
a.flatten.flatten // List[String] = List(book eraser -> pen , confidence :66.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to add collect to @Gabriele answer to get the desired result.

```
scala> List(List(List(())), List(List("Ink -> pen eraser , confidence :100.0")), List(List(())),List(List("pen Ink -> eraser , confidence :100.0")), List(List(())), List(List("Ink eraser -> pen , confidence :100.0")))
res0: List[List[List[Any]]] = List(List(List(())), List(List(Ink -> pen eraser ,confidence :100.0)),List(List(())), List(List(pen Ink -> eraser , confidence :100.0)), List(List(())),List(List(Ink eraser -> pen , confidence :100.0)))

scala> res0.flatten.flatten.collect{case str: String => str}
res1: List[String] = List(Ink -> pen eraser , confidence :100.0, pen Ink -> eraser , confidence :100.0, Ink eraser -> pen , confidence :100.0)

scala> val a = List(List(List(())), List(List("Ink -> pen eraser , confidence :100.0")), List(List(())), List(List("pen Ink -> eraser , confidence :100.0")), List(List(())), List(List("Ink eraser -> pen , confidence :100.0")))
scala> res0.flatten.flatten.collect{case str: String => str}
res4: List[String] = List(Ink -> pen eraser , confidence :100.0, pen Ink -> eraser , confidence :100.0, Ink eraser -> pen , confidence :100.0)
```

Instead of collect, you can also use filter(_ != ())

Comment: in case there's a `Unit` in the list, yes that's the way to go. However it's not clear whether `()` is a `String` or `Unit` from the question.